# how to remove warnings regarding use of scanf in Qt?

Tags: qt, security, scanf

I used scanf() in my program,when I compile it I'm getting a lot of warnings regarding use of scanf as follows:
D:\myspace\projects\nnf\NNFAdaptor\NNFAdaptor\main.cpp
C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.

I also tried using _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS but it is not present in my Qt (headers),it is shown as error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` at the top of your main.cpp (before any `#includes`).

Answer (score 4):

That class of warnings is mostly wrong (particularly about what to use instead) but it really is true that you should not use `scanf`, because:

1. It is very easy to write a format specification that is dangerous in the same way that `gets` is dangerous, i.e. it will write past the end of a buffer without noticing.  It *is* possible to write format specifications that don't have this problem but it is much harder.
2. It is almost impossible to write a `scanf`-based input parser that can handle ill-formed input reliably.
3. Overflow in any numeric conversion is technically undefined behavior, which means the C library is allowed to crash your program just because someone typed too many digits.  (Good C libraries will not do anything worse than produce garbage in your result variable, but that can itself be a headache.)

You should **not** use `scanf_s` instead; it attempts to paper over problem 1 but doesn't entirely succeed, and it doesn't address problems 2 and 3 at all.  Since you are using Qt, I recommend:

- Read entire lines into `std::string`s using `std::getline`.
- Parse them with `QRegExp`.
- Convert numeric strings to numbers with e.g. `QString::toDouble`.

If your input syntax is more complicated than regexes can handle, investigate `QLALR`.