# typecasting char pointer to float in C

Tags: c, parsing, casting

I have a flat file with the ff data:

```
date;quantity;price;item
```

I want create a data record using the following struct:

```
typedef struct {
  char * date, * item;
  int quantity;
  float price, total;
} expense_record;
```

I created the following initializing method:

```
expense_record initialize(char * date, int quantity, char *price, char *item) {
  expense_record e;
  e.date = date;
  e.quantity = quantity;
  e.item = item;
  /* set price */
  return e;
}
```

My question is how to set the price as `float` (as required by the struct) from the `char *price`. The closest I got, i.e. without generating a compiler error was

```
 e.price = *(float *)price
```

but this results in segmentation faults.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you pass to `initialize` as parameter `price`?

Comment: So you have a price in human readable format, and would like to convert it to a float? In that case, you have to parse it, as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951019/convert-string-to-float) ... Type casting is not for this purpose...

Comment: what do you do with `quantity`?

Comment: @us2012 @ppeterka66 Yes, I have a `price` in human readable format, e.g. 10.50 which is passed to the `initialize` method as `char * price`.

Comment: @Rohan, I will want to use `quantity` to compute the `total` later after setting the `price`, i.e. `e.total = quantity*price`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the <del>`strtod`</del> [`strtof`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtof) library function (include `<stdlib.h>`).  Relatedly, if the calling code uses anything other than [`strtoul`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul) to convert `quantity` from text to an `int`, that is probably a bug (the only exception I can think of would be, if for some reason `quantity` can be negative, then you would want `strtol` instead).

Comment: I accepted this answer because this addresses the main question above regarding "casting" a text/string to a float. Instead of `strod`, though, I used `strtof`.

Comment: This is not called "casting" in this context. This would be "parsing".

Comment: I, uh, tend to forget `strtof` exists (because the analogous `strtoi` doesn't).  You're quite right, though.

Answer (score 1):

To convert text to a `float`, use `strtof()`.  `strtod()` is better for `double`.
Your initialize routine likely wants a *copy* of the `date, etc.
A suggested improved routine follows:

```
expense_record initialize(const char * date, int quantity, const char *price, const char *item) {
  expense_record e;
  char *endptr;
  e.date = strdup(date);
  e.quantity = quantity;
  e.item = strdup(item);
  if (!e.date || !e.item) {
    ; // handle out-of -memory
  }
  e.price = strtof(price, &endptr); 
  if (*endptr) {
    ; // handle price syntax error
  }
  return e;
}
```

BTW: Recommend an additional change to pass into your initialization the destination record, but that gets into higher level architecture.

Comment: although I limited my question to casting or converting a `char *`, the answer you posted provides a more thorough review of the code. Thank you for the additional insights. Why would you suggest a `copy` of the date and others? Also, I tried `e.total = e.quantity*e.price` but don't get the expected results (really big numbers).

Comment: One needs to see the code that calls `initialize` to properly address the need (or not) for the `strdup()`.  I suspect your code will.

Comment: What value is a sample errant `e.total`, `e.quantity` and `e.price`?  Maybe invalid `e.quantity` or missing prototype for `strtof()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are having a segmentation fault because a `float` have 4 Bytes: when you make `*(float *)price` you are accesing to the first 4 Bytes of price, so if price´s size is smaller than 4 chars, you will have an error.

I think that the best you can do is read a `float` instead a `char *` when you parse the data (as i supose yo do with quantity), for example `fscanf (pFile, "%s;%d;%f;%s", &date, &quantity, &price, &item);`

or convert to `float` in `initialize` with [strtod](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod) instead of make a cast.

Comment: You can't count on a crash happening if "price's size is smaller than 4 chars"; contrariwise there are several reasons why it might crash even if there are `sizeof(float)` bytes of accessible memory at that address (misalignment, loading a signaling NaN with FPU exceptions enabled, ...); also, [`scanf` should never be used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067147/how-to-remove-warnings-regarding-use-of-scanf-in-qt/17067360#17067360).

Comment: You have discovered me two new interesting topics about memory, thanks.

But about scanf i do not agree: maybe is not the safest if you do not use taking the propers precautions, but since it is in the stdlib for me is valid. Besides, a query about qt is not the most appropriate argument when this question is about c.

Comment: The C standard library is very old and contains many things that are, at least, poorly designed, at worst, catastrophically dangerous.  Nobody would argue with the assertion that `gets` should never be used, ne?  It is *just as impossible* to use `scanf` safely (thanks to the "input overflow causes undefined behavior" issue).  That old answer of mine contains the clearest explanation of *why* `scanf` should never be used; I admit the advice for what to do instead is not helpful in *this* context, but there are plenty of obvious options (you mention one: `strtod`).

Comment: Ok, scanf is not safe to read strings (% s), which can produce an overflow of entry, but for all other data types i am not so sure, for example, since scanf  used internally strtod for read floats, scanf("%f", &number) is as safe as calling strtod, and for more complex entries, scanf can give more funcinalidades scanf("%f;%f", &n1, &n2)

Comment: No, in fact, `scanf("%f", &n);` *is not* safe.  Input overflow causes undefined behavior.  The C runtime is allowed to *crash* if the *user types too many digits*.  This is not the case for `strtof`.