# Strings, char array sizes, and calloc --- what causes this segmentation fault?

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory, segmentation-fault

What follows are abbreviated just to keep this question short (no check for null, etc.).

**program1.c**

```
main()
{
   char *aString = calloc(10, sizeof(char));

   printf("Enter string: ");
   scanf("%s", aString);

   printf("You typed in %s\n", aString);
}
```

**program2.c**

```
main()
{
   char aString[10];

   printf("Enter string: ");
   scanf("%s", aString);

   printf("You typed in %s\n", aString);
}
```

**program1.c** will let me enter characters seemingly forever.  I've entered 2000+ characters and the program will execute without error, despite the fact that this is "undefined behavior".

**program2.c** will let me enter more than 10 characters, but if get close to like 30 or 40 characters, it will give me a segmentation fault.

---

Now my limited understanding from class and other tutorials tells me that both of these programs are doing the same thing under the hood --- setting aside a piece of memory intended to be an array of chars of length 10.  But it seems that program2.c's implementation provides some degree of safety.  Or is the segmentation fault error completely random when you exceed the granted memory space, and I just happen to be getting it with program2.c just because that's the mood my computer is in right now?

What is the difference between program1.c and program2.c, and which is the "safer" method of entering a string?  I realize there are other methods which may be even better, but I'm curious about the comparison between just these two.

Comment: They're not doing the same thing under the hood, since the memory allocated, statically or dynamically, isn't at the same place (stack vs heap, respectively). Safer to use `fgets` to limit size of string entered.

Comment: Neither of them is safe: it doesn't crash does not mean that it is safe. You may refer to the infamous "heartbleed" bug.

Comment: Some observations: The prototype of main is `int main(int,char**)` or `int main(void)`. `sizeof(char)` is per definitionem 1. You might consider using `"%9s"` to avoid a buffer overrun on `char[10]`.

Comment: Let me guess that you can enter perhaps 4095-4 chars with prog 1. Calloc() will on modern systems provide a whole memory page to the process which would be used up in chunks by subsequent [mc]allocs, typically in ascending order. Only with special debugging libraries may your poiner be _at the end_ of that page so that overwriting segfaults immediatley, instead of corrupting data in memory which was allocated later.

Comment: This code is equally safe as using `gets` ... for some reason people jump all over `gets` posts but don't react the same way to `scanf("%s"` posts

Answer (score 2):

The two are *not* the same under the hood.

**program1** is calling `calloc` to allocate memory from *the heap*.

**program2** has been compiled to reserve additional space on *the stack* when the function is called.

Both programs are *exploitable* because you are not checking any bounds when you call `scanf()`. He is free to write as many bytes as he wishes to either buffer.  The solution here is `scanf("%9s", aString)`, which tells `scanf` to only write up to 9+1 bytes.

- [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

Comment: Note that C does neither require or specify 'heap' or 'stack'.  In proper terminology, there are two differences.  In the first program, aString is a pointer (type char*) which points to memory with so-called dynamic duration.  In the 2nd program, aString is an array (type char[10]) of automatic duration.

Comment: @fstd Thanks for pointing that out. I often get too ingrained in "modern" or "common" architectures, but you are technically correct. However, I'm reluctant to add even more complexity to my text.

Comment: Interesting. Two answers from 10k+ rep users, both downvoted without comment.

Comment: perhaps we ran afoul of the 'undefined means purple unicorns are just as likely' crowd.

Comment: @AShelly Indeed. They seem to forget that a "segmentation fault" is not defined by the C spec either, so certainly we should be allowed to constrain our answers to platforms that exhibit such an error.

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but I do think that merely saying "both programs are equally invalid" is not a complete answer to the question.  The OP will probably acquire more of a clue if we take the trouble to explain *why* one instance of UB causes a crash and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Although neither program is safe, the likely reason you are seeing the behavior is that program B allocates the array on the stack, and as soon as you get out of bounds you are overwriting other useful things like the stack frame of the `scanf` call.

Whereas program A allocates heap memory, and since you are not doing anything else in this toy program, the memory you are writing into is unused.

In any real program, both are equally unsafe.

*Note: This out-of-bounds behavior is undefined by the C standard, and the compiler could theoretically be doing anything. But in most common real-world compilers, the above is most likely what actually happens.*

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a typical modern operating system, your program 1 does not crash because `calloc` had to request an entire page (4096 bytes of RAM, usually) from the OS to satisfy the request for 10 bytes.  If you feed that program sufficiently many characters, it *will* crash.  However, writing even one byte more than the overtly requested size (10 bytes) is forbidden, and has an excellent chance of corrupting the internal data structure used to keep track of "heap" allocations.  It is probable that if you added another `malloc` or `free` call to this program, after the `scanf`, it would crash inside that `malloc` or `free`.  By way of illustration, consider this program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char *p = malloc(23);
  memcpy(p, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx", 25);
  char *q = malloc(1);
  return 0;
}
```

## ➽

```
$ MALLOC_CHECK_=1 ./a.out 
*** Error in `./a.out': malloc: top chunk is corrupt: 0x0000000001bc4020 ***
```

(On *this* system, copying only 24 bytes does not crash.  Do not rely on this information.)

Program 2, meanwhile, is probably crashing not because the `scanf` call wrote all the way to unmapped memory (which, for similar reasons, would require far more bytes of input) but because data on the stack is very densely packed and it clobbered something critical, e.g. the address to which `main` should return.

In a program that does anything even a little more complicated than your examples, both "techniques" are equally dangerous -- both heap and stack overflows can and have lead to catastrophic security holes.

---

You explicitly asked for a comparison between your two unsafe techniques, but for the benefit of future readers I am going to describe two *much better* techniques for reading strings from standard input.  If your C library includes it, the best option is [`getline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline), which (in a simple program like this) would be used like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *line = 0; 
    size_t n = 0;
    ssize_t r;

    fputs("Enter a string: ", stdout);
    fflush(stdout);

    r = getline(&line, &n, stdin);
    if (r == -1) {
        perror("getline");
        return 1;
    }
    if (r > 0 && line[r-1] == '\n')
        line[r-1] = '\0';

    printf("You entered %s\n", line);
    free(line);
    return 0;
}
```

If you *don't* have `getline`, and you need to read an arbitrarily long string from the user, your best option is to implement `getline` yourself ([gnulib has an implementation you can borrow, if your code can be released under the GPL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/getline.html)).  But an acceptable alternative in many cases is to place an upper limit on input length, at which point you can use `fgets`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LEN 81

int main(void)
{
    char *line = malloc(MAX_LINE_LEN);
    size_t n;

    fputs("Enter a string: ", stdout);
    fflush(stdout);

    if (!fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LEN, stdin)) {
        perror("fgets");
        return 1;
    }
    n = strlen(line);
    if (line[n] != '\n') {
        fprintf(stderr, "string too long - %u characters max\n", MAX_LINE_LEN);
        return 1;
    }
    line[n] = '\0';

    printf("You entered %s\n", line);
    free(line);
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

1. `sizeof(char) == 1` **by definition**; therefore, `sizeof(char)` should never appear in well-written code.  If you want to use `calloc` to allocate a prezeroed array of characters, write `calloc(1, nchars)`.
2. [Never use `scanf`, `fscanf`, or `sscanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067147/how-to-remove-warnings-regarding-use-of-scanf-in-qt/17067360#17067360).
3. Do not confuse `fgets` with `gets`.  `fgets` is safe if used correctly; [it is *impossible* to use `gets` safely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346598/gets-function-in-c).