# String input using C scanf_s

Tags: c, string, scanf, c11, tr24731

I've been trying to look for answer myself, but I can't find one. 
I want to insert a part of the programming that reads in a string like "Hello" and stores and can display it when I want, so that `printf("%s", blah);` produces `Hello`.

Here's the code part that's giving me trouble

```
char name[64];
scanf_s("%s", name);
printf("Your name is %s", name);
```

I know that `printf` isn't the problem; the program crashes after something is input after a prompt. Please help?

Comment: The 'secure' version of `scanf` requires that you supply the length of the buffer.

Comment: Just use `scanf()`, instead of this `scanf_s()`. Or, even better, `fgets()`.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace for the same? If yes please post it.

Comment: If using `scanf` you must specify the length to avoid a buffer overflow: `scanf("%63s", name);`

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17067317/830514, I am using VS 2013, C program.

Answer (score 7):

From the specification of `fscanf_s()` in Annex K.3.5.3.2 of the ISO/IEC 9899:2011 standard:

> The `fscanf_s` function is equivalent to `fscanf` except that the `c`, `s`, and `[` conversion
>   specifiers apply to a pair of arguments (unless assignment suppression is indicated by a
>   `*`). The first of these arguments is the same as for `fscanf`. That argument is
>   immediately followed in the argument list by the second argument, which has type
>   `rsize_t` and gives the number of elements in the array pointed to by the first argument
>   of the pair. If the first argument points to a scalar object, it is considered to be an array of
>   one element.

and:

> The `scanf_s` function is equivalent to `fscanf_s` with the argument `stdin`
>   interposed before the arguments to `scanf_s`.

MSDN says similar things ([`scanf_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) and [`fscanf_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ybhk9kc.aspx)).

Your code doesn't provide the length argument, so some other number is used.  It isn't determinate what value it finds, so you get eccentric behaviour from the code.  You need something more like this, where the newline helps ensure that the output is actually seen.

```
char name[64];
if (scanf_s("%s", name, sizeof(name)) == 1)
    printf("Your name is %s\n", name);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the third argument of `scanf_s` be cast to `(unsigned int)` as `sizeof` returns a value of type `size_t`?

Comment: @CoolGuy:  If you're going to cast it, it should be cast to `rsize_t` (see the quote in the answer), but K.3.3 **Common definitions `<stddef.h>`** says (in its entirety):
_The header <stddef.h> defines a type.The type is
`rsize_t`
which is the type `size_t`._ and references footnote 385, which says: _See the description of the `RSIZE_MAX` macro in `<stdint.h>`._  The discussion of `RSIZE_MAX` is considerably more extensive, but the intent is that it should usually be smaller than `SIZE_MAX`, with `SIZE_MAX >> 1` being a suggested size.

Answer (score 5):

I used this very often in my university classes so this should work fine in Visual Studio (tested in VS2013):

```
char name[64]; // the null-terminated string to be read
scanf_s("%63s", name, 64);
// 63 = the max number of symbols EXCLUDING '\0'
// 64 = the size of the string; you can also use _countof(name) instead of that number
// calling scanf_s() that way will read up to 63 symbols (even if you write more) from the console and it will automatically set name[63] = '\0'
// if the number of the actually read symbols is < 63 then '\0' will be stored in the next free position in the string
// Please note that unlike gets(), scanf() stops reading when it reaches ' ' (interval, spacebar key) not just newline terminator (the enter key)
// Also consider calling "fflush(stdin);" before the (eventual) next scanf()
```

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf_s` function is equivalent to `scanf` except that `%c`, `%s`, and `%[` conversion specifiers each expect two arguments (the usual pointer and a value of type `rsize_t` indicating the size of the receiving array, which may be 1 when reading with a `%c` into a single char)

Your code doesn't provide the size of receiving array, also the variable `name` is a pointer pointing to the first character of the array, so it contains the address of `name[0]`. Therefore your first argument `name` in `scanf_s` is correct because name is a pointer, also note that, for the second argument you can't insert the size of a pointer like `sizeof(name)` because it is always same. You need to specify the size of your char array (`name[64]`), so for the second argument you should insert `sizeof(name)` or `sizeof(char[64])` or `64*sizeof(char)`.

You can correct your code as follows:

```
char name[64];
if (scanf_s("%s", name, sizeof(name)) == 1)
    printf("Your name is %s\n", name);
```

Comment: `sizeof(name[64])` should be `sizeof(name)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a part of code that works for me fine:

```
char name[64];
scanf_s("%63s", name,(unsigned)_countof(name));
printf("Your name is %s", name);
```

For more information here is a link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=msvc-170

Best Regards

Comment: That does not look portable though.

Answer (score -1):

you should do this : `scanf ("%63s", name);`

**Update**:

The below code worked for me:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void) { 
    char name[64]; 
    scanf ("%63s", name); 
    printf("Your name is %s", name); 
    return 0; 
}
```

if you are using visual studio, 
go to `Project properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++-> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions` click on `edit` and add `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` click ok, apply the settings and run again.

Note: this is only good if you are doing your homework or something like that and it's not recommended for production.

Comment: Still didn't work, it doesn't crash anymore, but the printf won't show the result.

Comment: I tried this and it worked, #include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[64];
    scanf ("%63s", name);
    printf("Your name is %s", name);
    return 0;
}

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio and it won't let me use scanf, just scanf_s, but even with the buffer, it won't work, just skips the %s in the printf afterwards.

Comment: you started a visual c++ project?

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming that that's the problem... but what specifically?

Comment: go to Project properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions click on edit and add _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS click ok, apply the settings and run the project

Answer (score -1):

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
      char name[64];

      printf("Enter your name: ");
      scanf("%s", name);
      printf("Your name is %s\n", name);

     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: isn't it : scanf("%s", name); (no '&')?

Comment: '&' is not required here. The array name itself will give the address of the array.

Comment: The `&` on `&name` does no harm, but is not needed. Leave it off because you understand the relationship between arrays and pointers. If you *don't* understand that relationship go read about it and then leave the extra `&` off.

Comment: I changed it. Sorry, just a habit.

Comment: Finally found the comment, still doesn't work. I used yours as a test run and the command screen just shows:
     Enter your name:
     Your name isPress any key to close

Comment: The first line is prompting you for input, after you type in a name the program will display it back to you.

Comment: @dmckee, `name` is correct and `&name` is wrong, however on common implementations both of those have the same representation, so it usually works.  The `%s` specifier expects a `char *`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I agree that the correct for is without, but I don't think that it is by chance that it works the wrong way. I can't quote chapter and verse, but I think this is required: `&name` returns a pointer to a `char` array not a pointer to `char`, but scanf is  variadic so all pointers are converted to `void*`, and a char array *must* be stored in a way that allows pointer indexing to work on it, so the `&name` form must work even though it is incorrect. Or something like that.

Comment: Hmmm ... may be wrong about the pointer conversion. In which case a hypothetical compiler that stores pointers to arrays differently than other pointers could conceivably show different behavior.

Comment: @dmckee: The notation `&name` generates a `char (*)[64]` in the context of the question (`char name[64];`).  The `%s` format expects a `char *`, and simply referencing `name` yields a `char *`.  As you can see, the two types are quite radically different.  The unfortunate curiosity is that the value of `&name` viewed as a `void *` is the same as the value of `name` viewed as a `void *`.  This allows `scanf("%63s", &name)` to 'work', but doesn't stop it being incorrect.

Comment: @dmckee:  Also note that the compiler does not do any type conversions on the pointers passed to `scanf()` — only integer types shorter than `int` or floating type shorter than `double` are subject to _default argument promotion_ when passed to variadic functions such as `scanf()`, and since `scanf()` only takes pointers (unlike `scanf_s()` which also takes some integers), there is no default argument promotion in valid calls to `scanf()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char name[64];
  printf("Enter your name: ");
  gets(name);
  printf("Your name is %s\n", name);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Comment: Ah, yes. A code snippet with no context and doesn't answer the question. Brilliant.