# Triggering break keyword with string variable in c language

Tags: c

I am a programming noob. I was working on the assignment on my own and i hit the wall right now and any help will be appreciated.

I made loop where i get input for names, rates and hours and if user type -1 it will break the loop and move on to the next loop. Everything is fine except if i type -1 for name it just doesn't break. I know the variable is string and -1 is integer and i just can't figure out what should i do to make this work.

here is part of my stupid code.

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)

{
    puts("\ntype name: (type -1 to quit) \n");
    scanf_s("%s", &name[i], 20);
    puts("\ntype hourly rate: (type -1 to quit) \n");
    scanf_s("%f", &rate[i]);
    puts("\ntype hours worked: (type -1 to quit) \n");
    scanf_s("%f", &hours[i]);
    //if break keyword needed.

    if (*name == -1 || rate[i] == -1 || hours[i] == -1)
    {
        break;
    }
```

Comment: [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/)

Comment: Why `"-1"` in a string field?  Why not just an empty string?  `if (!strlen(name))`

Comment: It  is sadly a part of assignment, but thank you for teaching another function.

Comment: You can not compare strings with ==, and you can not compare strings to numbers. Use atoi() to convert a string to integer, or use strcmp() with "-1" (string representation of -1).

Comment: Thank you for the help. i will try both methods

Comment: i tried atoi(), and it worked thank you.

Comment: @Tibrogargan [Why shouldn't I use atoi()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Comment: @linuxfan it's better to use `strcmp` in this case

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`strcmp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) like

```
scanf_s("%19s", name[i], 20);
if(strcmp(name[i], "-1")==0)
{
    break;
}
```

`strcmp()` compares the two strings and returns `0` if both are same.

Leading spaces are not a problem and will be ignored. So `-1` will still be read as `-1`.

Otherwise you could first convert the string in `name[i]` to an integer and then see if the resultant number is `-1`. For that approach, see [How to convert a string to integer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7021725/5375464).

---

Also, if `name[i]` is a character array of size 20, instead of

```
scanf_s("%s", &name[i], 20);
```

you probably need

```
scanf_s("%19s", name[i], 20);
```

as `name[i]` itself is the address since array names decay to pointers to their first element in C.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23378636/5375464) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx).