# Quick question, why is scanf_s throwing an exception in runtime here? I am very confused

Tags: c, runtime-error, c11

I am trying to use scanf (or some variant like scanf_s) to send a character array from the stdin stream into a (pre-defined) character array variable.

The error (unhanled exception) is thrown at runtime by windows as soon as the user hits enter; it is triggered as soon as scanf() is called..

I am new to working with C and just trying to get the basics down of working with variables in a more low level way, its fun but sometimes frustrating

Should I just make my own scanf function? - How would one do that?

Below is the code that isnt working, in its simplest form so easy for you to read.. (Its literally just the scanf part thats throwing an exception.. gah!)

Below the code is the error message

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char string[20];

    printf("%s\n", string);

    scanf_s("%s", &string);



    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Error is:

```
Exception thrown at 0x1011E63C (ucrtbased.dll) in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00760000.
Unhandled exception at 0xFEFEFEFE in Project.exe: 0xC00001A5: An invalid exception handler routine has been detected (parameters: 0x00000003).
```

Comment: `printf("%s\n", string);` - what exactly is supposed to be printed here?

Comment: Also [`scanf_s` does **not** work like `scanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378636/string-input-using-c-scanf-s). Also you do not need `&` for reading a *string* in `scanf`.

Comment: Have you thought about reading the manual pages for these two functions?

Comment: I have tried to read the manual pages but they involve more abstract language which im not familiar with yet - thought i would just try and get a quick answer

The first printf(); is meaningless im just playing around here - literally started C two days ago aha.. im just playing

I have got this to work by doing

scanf_s("%s", string, 20);

Hmm

Comment: @OllieHancock Stackoverflow does not work the way you seem to think it works. Please read [ask] and [faq].

Comment: Please could you give me the URL for the manual page that you read

Comment: Anyone using (or thinking of using) any of the (not really) safer functions such as `scanf_s()` should read [**Field Experience With Annex K — Bounds Checking Interfaces**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm):  "Microsoft Visual Studio implements an early version of the APIs. However, the implementation is incomplete and conforms neither to C11 nor to the original TR 24731-1. ...  As a result of the numerous deviations from the specification the Microsoft implementation cannot be considered conforming or portable."

Comment: (cont) "...  **Using the APIs has been seen to lead to worse quality, less secure software than relying on established approaches or modern technologies.** More effective and less intrusive approaches have become commonplace and are often preferred by users and security experts alike.  Therefore, we propose that Annex K be either removed from the next revision of the C standard, or deprecated and then removed."

Answer (score 2):

Few things:

1. Why are you calling `printf` on the uninitialized buffer `string`? That is undefined behavior.
2. To use `scanf_s` properly to read a string, use this: `scanf_s("%19s\n", string, 20);`. The general pattern is `"%s", buffer, X` where `X` is the capacity of the buffer. Also, notice that it's `string`, not `&string`.

That is, if you insist on using `scanf_s` at all; `fgets` is better for reading strings.

Comment: Is `"%X-1s"` required for `scanf_s`? That kind of makes passing the size as an argument redundant.

Comment: @Kevin read the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(STDIO%2Fscanf_s);k(scanf_s);k(DevLang-C%2B%2B);k(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019

Comment: Hmm, the example on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) disagrees with that. Could be a difference between C11 and whatever microsoft supports? Honestly I don't understand why you need to specify in both places. One would be sufficient.

Comment: 1. Thats not to do with the question its just some left over code I accidentally copied in
2. Thanks! :D

Thanks man x

Comment: Do you know where I can find some very current (like 2019) documentation for C? All of the tutorials ive found stick to old standards using things like scanf and scanf_s -- I dont feel confident enough to dive in to using something like fgets with little online doc' , yknow?

Thank you so much for your help btw also how does one enter a line break in these comments ffs aha

Comment: @OllieHancock `scanf` and `scanf_s` aren't outdated or deprecated, but using either of them as the go-to method for reading input from the user has never been a good idea. Asking for educational advice is off topic on Stack Overflow, though there may be other Stack Exchange sites where it is appropriate.

Comment: According to the MS docs, no, a field width is *not* required in the format.  What's required is a separate buffer-size argument.  Where a field width suitable for the actual array argument is used, `scanf_s` indeed has no advantage over `scanf`.

Comment: Also, although `scanf_s` is not deprecated, it ***is*** optional, and not widely implemented, and the version of that and the other `*_s` functions that were standardized disagree in some details with the version implemented by their primary champion (Microsoft).  The mismatch makes it unlikely that they will *ever* be widely implemented.  Many consider them flawed, and their supposed additional security illusory.  My advice: don't use the `*_s` unless forced to.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Updated my answer