# Problems with limiting a string length in C

Tags: c, scanf, c-strings

I'm relatively new to coding and do not understand why I'm receiving an Exception thrown with a simple scanf.

```
char word[15];

printf("\nEnter a word: ");
scanf_s("%15s", word);
```

Comment: You need to account for the extra null on the end which is needed to terminate a string. A string of length 15 characters will need to be 16 bytes in length.

Comment: I hope you're not using `scanf_s()` because your compiler told you `scanf()` is "deprecated".  Because `scanf()` is **not** deprecated.

Comment: `scanf_s` needs the buffer size. Look it up in the documentation: "_If nothing helps, read the manual_"

Comment: ... and enable the warnings, and read them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`scanf_s` requires a third argument, the `sizeof` the buffer:

```
scanf_s("%s", word, sizeof(word));
```

`scanf_s` can either be Microsoft-specific or the one defined by the C standard but which isn't mandatory to be implemented in every C implementation. Dependent on which one you use you either need to cast the `sizeof()` argument to `unsigned`(Microsoft implementation) or cast it to `rsize_t` (C standard).

Related:

- [Difference between scanf and scanf_s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21434735/12139179)
- [String input using C scanf_s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23378636/12139179)

Note that you also should check the return value of `scanf_s`.

```
if ( scanf_s("%s", word, (unsigned) sizeof(word)) != 1 )
{
    // error routine.
}
```

If you want to write portable code, use `fgets()` instead:

```
if ( !fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin) )
{
   // error routine.
}
```

Comment: Size type can be a problem as [MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019) expects `unsigned`, yet `sizeof()` returns `size_t`.  MS promotes `(unsigned)_countof(s)`

Comment: "scanf_s is Microsoft-specific" --> `scanf_s()` is specified in the annex of C11,C18 needing a `size_t` agreement.  Many C11 compilers do not implement this function.

Comment: Microsoft's calling convention would probably work exactly equally with `size_t`... but they just want to force people to write as unportable code as possible.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala  It breaks when `size_t` differs in size from `unsigned` - restricts what a future MS compiler can do. MS C variation on C11 and non-compilation (even in 2020) with C99 certainly looks inconsistent.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `size_t` already does differ from unsigned, but the calling convention might be compatible nevertheless...

Answer (score 3):

## Strings

Strings in C are represented using an array of characters.

These arrays must be terminated using a null character `\0`, as the C standard library is written assuming you will be writing strings this way.

When you define the array `char word[15]` you are allocating enough memory to store 14 characters plus the null character.

Answer (score 2):

The function `scanf_s` for the conversion specifier `s` requires an addition argument that specifiers the size of the input buffer.

You could write for example (if it is the Microsoft implementation of scanf_s)

```
scanf_s("%14s", word, ( unsigned )sizeof( word ) );
```

or (if it is the standard scanf_s)

```
scanf_s("%14s", word, ( rsize_t )sizeof( word ) );
```

Also the length should be specified equal to `sizeof( word ) - 1` that is equal to `14`. One character is reserved for the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

Comment: Isn't the precision redundant in the case of `scanf_s`?

Comment: Vlad, What advantage do you see using a _width_ in the format versus `scanf_s("%s", word, ( unsigned_or_size_t) sizeof word);`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Same place. Same time. Same thought. :-)

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio It allows to read exactly 14 characters and the call will be successfull.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there! As you may already know strings in C are stored and managed in memory using an array of chars that terminates with a NULL character ('\0').

In short, if you want to limit the length of your string to say, 15 characters, you just add 1 to that to account for the NULL terminating character and voila! Your code works. A coder's mnemotechnic device:

```
Desired MAX number of character = Desired MAX number of character + 1;
// or the shortened 
the Desired MAX number of character += 1;
```

Also, bear in mind that, as mentioned above, scanf_s requires an additional argument that specifies the size of the input buffer. So your code would look like:

```
scanf_s("%16s", word, (unsigned)sizeof( word ));
```

Hope it helps and happy coding!