# why isn't this code storing the words in this 2d array?

Tags: c

The code is suppose to take in 6 words starting with a, b or c and put them in to each respective array. Only problem is that it doesn't store anything at all no matter what I do.
The printf in the last part of the code is suppose to spit everything that I typed in out but it's giving me nothing but blanks...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char startswithA[6][10] = {};
char startswithB[6][10] = {};
char startswithC[6][10] = {};
char holder[6][10] = {};

printf("Enter a word starting with a, b or c (write 2 of each)\n");
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i = i + 1)
{
    printf("Now entering word #%d\n", i+1);
    scanf_s("%s", &holder[i]);
    if(holder[i][0] == 'a')
    {   
        for(int a = 0; a < 10; a = a + 1)
        {
            holder[i][a] = startswithA[i][a];
        }
    }
    else if (holder[i][0] == 'b')
    {
        for(int a = 0; a < 10; a = a + 1)
        {
            holder[i][a] = startswithB[i][a];
        }
    }
    else if (holder[i][0] == 'c')
    {
        for(int a = 0; a < 10; a = a + 1)
        {
            holder[i][a] = startswithC[i][a];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("something out of bound was typed in");
    }
}
for(int b = 0; b < 6; b = b + 1)
{
    printf("%s %s %s\n", startswithA[b], startswithB[b], startswithC[b]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Besides that issue with swapping the names in your assignments, there are some bugs with reading your input: `scanf_s` requires an extra parameter specifying the length of your input buffer. See [String input using C scanf_s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378636/string-input-using-c-scanf-s) for more details. Not providing that parameter causes undefined behaviour. Also `holder[i]` is an array of `char` that decays to a pointer to `char`. You should remove the `&` from it.

Comment: @Gerhardh that's odd, my professor never said anything about that part for scanf_s being mandatory. what kind of bugs are we talking about here.

Comment: Whatever your professor tells you, you should always read up the documentation of functions you are using to get familiar. As you can see in the link I provided, that parameter is mandatory for strings. The function also has no mechanism to know you did not provide it. A likely result is that it will just take the value that it finds in the place where the buffer size is expected, i.e. in a certain place on the stack or in a register. As you did not put anything there, it will read garbage resulting in limiting the string to less than buffer size or to allow overflow with too large length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is typo

```
holder[i][a] = startswithA[i][a];
```

Did you mean?

```
startswithA[i][a] = holder[i][a];
```