# c++ fscanf %c dosn't work properly

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I have an input file with this content:

```
123 A 012345 ABC
```

My code is:

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE* fin;
    FILE* fout;
    int l;
    char d;
    char pk[ASD];
    char cd[BCD];

    fin = fopen("a.i1", "r");
    fscanf(fin, "%d %c %s %[^\n]", &l, &d, pk, cd);
    fclose(fin);

    fout = fopen("b.out", "w+");
    fprintf(fout, "%d %c %s %s", l, d, pk, cd);
    fclose(fout);
    return 0;
}
```

My output is:

```
123   012345 ABC
```

(in notepad++ between 123 and 012345 is NULL) 
Why "d" does not get value 'A'?

If I read like this:

```
fscanf(fin, "%d%c %s %[^\n]", &l, &d, pk, cd);
```

I got this:

```
10   B 01010112345 ABBA
```

But I don't know why.

Comment: Please add some proper formatting.

Comment: Please show us how you are doing the output.

Comment: @Codor sorry, when submited, saw that tabs where lost, was going to fix that.

Comment: Why stop there? Show us _everything_. Show us what/how `l`, `w` and `m` are declared/initialized. Show us how `fin` and `fout` is opened. What is the return value of `fscanf()`? etc.

Comment: When expanded to a complete program in the obvious fashion, this works for me on OSX.  Need to see a complete working example to know whether this is a bug in your code or a bug in your C library.  [Never use scanf for anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067147/how-to-remove-warnings-regarding-use-of-scanf-in-qt/17067360#17067360).

Comment: What character is between `123` and `A`? Is it a space or something different? Could it be that a space is read and printed?

Comment: It [works for me (at ideone)](http://ideone.com/Ltogv8)

Comment: @Codor nvm, will put in start because of tabs.

Comment: Did you copy and paste the posted code or did you retype it?

Comment: Can you show a hex dump of the input file ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust 0000-0010:  31 30 20 42-20 30 31 30-31 30 31 31-32 33 34 35  10.B.010 10112345
0000-0019:  20 41 42 42-41 0d 0a 0d-0a                       .ABBA... .

Comment: This is not the input file, is it ?

Comment: Your hex dump shows: '1', '0', ' ', 'B', ' ', '0', '1', '0', ... Which doesn't match the input data to your post.

Comment: @Yves Daoust with other programm, I am prety sure this is correct: 31 30 20 42 20 30 31 30 31 30 31 31 32 33 34 35 20 41 42 42 41 0D 0A 31 35 20 41 20 30 32 30 32 30 32 31 33 34 35 36 20 55 32

Comment: Oh here is other text, 10 B 01010112345 ABBA and 15 A 02020213456 U2 but the problems is the same ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually `fscanf(fin,"%c",&c)` inputs a single character in your case that character is space (right after 123 in input file) so when

```
fscanf(fin, "%d %c %s %[^\n]", &l, &d, w, m);
```

is executed

```
l contains 123, 
d contains (space), 
w contains "A" (next string after space)
and 
m contains "012345 ABC" (because delimiter is '\n')
```

so basically

```
fprintf(fout, "%d %c %s %s", l, d, w, m);
```

will print the expected value. but i assume values are not stored in the variable you expected.

Check your `fprintf` statement once you might have missed printing `w` so `"A"` is not printing

Comment: Nope, the whitespace in the conversion specification makes `scanf()` ignore whitespace in input.

Comment: oh yes @pmg, i didnt observed that
try re-installing the compiler or using different compiler
The program you posted working properly in my gcc compiler in Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score -1):

Test the return value from `fopen()` and `fscanf()`.

```
fin = fopen("a.i1", "r");
if (!fin) {
    perror("a.i1");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (fscanf(fin, "%d %c %s %[^\n]", &l, &d, pk, cd) != 4) {
    fprintf(stderr, "fscanf() did not manage to assign 4 values.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
fclose(fin);
```