# how to read specific value from file in c

Tags: c

if i have file contain students scores
for example this file

```
{ 
students scores :
100
90
83
70
}
```

how i can read just the values of scores with out reading "students scores :"???

mu code is already ok 
but the problem in reading values

this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    FILE *infile;
    double score, sum=0, average;
    int count=0, input_status;

    infile = fopen("scores.txt", "r");
    input_status = fscanf(infile, "%lf", &score);
    while (input_status != EOF) 
    {
        printf("%.2f\n ", score);
        sum += score;
        count++;
        input_status = fscanf(infile, "%lf",  &score);
    }
    average = sum / count;

    printf("\nSum of the scores is %f\n", sum);
    printf("Average score is %.2f\n", average);
    fclose(infile);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Files have no internal structure; you must somehow advance the read position over the leading "`{\nstudents scores :\n`" to get to the numbers.  The usual way to do this is to write a parser.  BTW, never use `scanf`.

Comment: A question which will determine how much trouble you need to go to is: Does this program need to cope gracefully with being fed input which is not as expected?

Comment: Is there any particular *reason* you don't want to read "students scores :"? Speed? Algorithmic elegance? Sensitivity to bad grammar?

Comment: @Zack "Never use scanf"? What?

Comment: @clcto [Not joking even a little.  Never. Use. Scanf.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067147/how-to-remove-warnings-regarding-use-of-scanf-in-qt/17067360#17067360)

Comment: That link is "don't use scanf in Qt"

Comment: One way is to do `getchar()` until you have had sufficient `\n`'s pass. Another way is to read every line into a string, and then use `sscanf` to look for doubles.  We can't say exactly without knowing what possible variations your input file might contain.

Comment: @MattMcNabb That link happens to be in the context of Qt, but it gives three reasons not to use scanf, none of which are specific to the context, and each of which is sufficient in itself to justify my position.

Answer (score 1):

Problems I see:

```
input_status = fscanf(infile, "%lf", &score);
while (input_status != EOF)
```

is not right. The returned value of `fscanf` will be `0` if the read was not successful and `1` if it was successful.

More importantly, you need to add code that skips everything upto the point where you expect to see the numbers.

```
char line[100];
while ( fgets(line, 100, infile) != NULL )
{
  // If the line containing "students scores :"
  // is found, break from the while loop.
  if (strstr(line, "students scores :") != NULL )
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

Then, change start of the lines that read the data into:

```
input_status = fscanf(infile, "%lf", &score);
while (input_status == 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly easy way to parse the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void)
   {
   FILE *infile;
   char  lineBuf[255+1];
   double score, sum=0, average;
   int count=0;
   int fieldsParsed;

   infile = fopen("scores.txt", "r");

   /** Read a line from the file. **/
   while(fgets(lineBuf, sizeof(lineBuf), infile))
      {
      /** Is the first character of the line a digit? **/
      if(!isdigit(*lineBuf))
         continue;  /* It is not a digit.  Go get the next line. */

      /** Convert the number string (in lineBuf) to an integer (score). **/
      score=atof(lineBuf);
      printf("fields[%d] %.2f\n ", fieldsParsed, score);
      sum += score;
      count++;
      }

   average = sum / count;

   printf("\nSum of the scores is %f\n", sum);
   printf("Average score is %.2f\n", average);
   fclose(infile);
//   getch(); Non-portable
   return(0);
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use fseek() to skip past the leading bytes to the numbers.