# Replacing characters in strings in C

Tags: c, string

I have recently started using C and am having trouble understanding the use of "&" and "*" and where to put them in my code. The current assignment I have requires me to take two inputs, the character in a string that a user would like to swap and the new character to replace it with. I am not allowed to use the String library. Here is my current code but for some reason, the output is never able to access "replacementchar[0]" and I have no clue why. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
if(response[0] == yes[0]){
        char replacechar[1];
        printf("What character do you want to replace: ");
        scanf("%s", replacechar);

        char newchar[1];
        printf("What is the replacement character: ");
        scanf("%s", newchar);

        printf("you want to replace %c with %c \n", replacechar[0], newchar[0]);
        for(int i = len-1; i > -1; --i){
            if(word[i] == replacechar[0] && word[i] != '\0'){
                printf("found one\n");
                word[i] = newchar[0];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @user3121023 Or somewhat more sanely, `%c` or `getchar()`.

Comment: Consider (use) `scanf(" %c", replacechar)` — read a single character skipping leading white space (such as the newline leftover from reading `response[0]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, * and & are pointer operators. * is used to create pointers variables and *dereference* them. & is used to get the memory address of something.

The following code (1) creates an int a, (2) creates an int pointer p using * and (3) sets the value of pointer p to the *memory address* of a using &.

```
int a;
int *p;
p = &a;

printf("%d", p);
printf("%d", *p);
```

The first print will return the value of p, which is the memory address of a. In the second print we *dereference* p, which gives us the data stored at that memory address--the value of int a.

There are other ways to use pointers. When you create an array...

```
int arr[10];
```

...you are implicitly creating a pointer ("arr") to the first element in your array. You can access elements if the array in several ways.

```
arr[5]
*(arr + 5)
```

Both get the 5th element of the array by looking at arr (the *memory address* of the first element) and adding 5, which gives us the *memory address* of the 5th element, then dereferencing that with * to get the value of the 5th element.

...

Your code is wrong not because of a misuse of & and *, but because of the behavior of scanf (which you [shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664664/scanf-regex-c/15664816#15664816) [really](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067147/how-to-remove-warnings-regarding-use-of-scanf-in-qt/17067360#17067360) use). Scanf writes to a buffer, which you then have to copy in order to save the value. Also, considering you're only scanning a single char, there's no need to use a char array. Check out this solution:

```
char buf, replacechar, newchar;
printf("What character do you want to replace: ");
scanf("%c", &buf);
replacechar = buf;

printf("What is the replacement character: ");
scanf("%s", &buf);
newchar = buf;

printf("You want to replace %c with %c\n", replacechar,
newchar);
for (int i = len-1; i > -1; --i) {
    if (word[i] == replacechar && word[i] != '\0') {
    printf("Found one!\n");
    word[i] = newchar;
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for the variable "buf". Just use `scanf("%c", &replacechar);` and `scanf("%c", &newchar);`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach besides `getchar` or `scanf` using either `%s` or `%c` is to use `fgets`.  Here `fgets` will read up to two characters from `stdin`. If `choice[1]` is a newline, only one other character was entered. Otherwise, clear `stdin` and prompt to try again.
The `replacement` function advances a pointer `text` through each character of the string until the character pointed to `*text` is the terminating zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char fgetschar ( void) {
    char choice[3] = "";

    do {
        if ( fgets ( choice, sizeof choice, stdin)) {//read two characters
            if ( '\n' == choice[0]) {//only newline
                printf ( "\nenter a character\n\ttry again\n");
                continue;
            }
            if ( '\n' != choice[1]) {//did not find expected newline
                while ( fgets ( choice, sizeof choice, stdin)) {
                    if ( '\n' == choice[0] || '\n' == choice[1]) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                choice[1] = 0;//to make the loop repeat
                printf ( "\nenter one character only\n\ttry again\n");
            }
        }
        else {
            fprintf ( stderr, "fgets EOF\n");
            exit ( EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    } while ( choice[1] != '\n');

    return choice[0];
}

int replacement ( char *text, char find, char sub) {
    int count = 0;

    while ( text && *text) {//not NULL and not terminating zero
        if ( *text == find) {
            *text = sub;
            ++count;
        }
        ++text;//advance to next character
    }

    return count;
}

int main ( void) {
    char replacechar = 0;
    char newchar = 0;
    char word[] = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z";

    int size = 21;
    int item = rand ( ) % ( size - (int)( size * 0.6));
    printf ( "item %d\n", item);

    printf ( "What character do you want to replace: ");
    fflush ( stdout);
    replacechar = fgetschar ( );
    printf ( "replace character: %c\n\n", replacechar);

    printf("What is the replacement character: ");
    fflush ( stdout);
    newchar = fgetschar ( );
    printf ( "replacement character: %c\n\n", newchar);

    int found = replacement ( word, replacechar, newchar);

    printf ( "found %d instances of %c\n", found, replacechar);

    printf ( "%s\n", word);

    return 0;
}
```